# 350+ errors: The type 'blah.blah.blah' already contains a definition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

What does this mean. Is it because I have two different .DBML files that contain the same database table?

```
...
Error   343 The type 'mvc.Models.Bundle' already contains a definition for 'BundleIcon' C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Models\Assets1.designer.cs   3438    17  mvc
Error   344 The type 'mvc.Models.Bundle' already contains a definition for 'isScorm'    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Models\Assets1.designer.cs   3459    15  mvc
Error   345 The type 'mvc.Models.Bundle' already contains a definition for 'scormPath'  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Models\Assets1.designer.cs   3480    17  mvc
Error   346 The type 'mvc.Models.Bundle' already contains a definition for 'CompanyID'  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Models\Assets1.designer.cs   3501    14  mvc
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you keep them in the same namespace this would occurr.

Comment: whould it be wrong to use two namespaces ?  I am using the two classes in MVC application. Ta

Answer (score 3):

OK, I came across this same error when adding another Linq-to-SQL .dbml.

The more specific cause is that you can not have 2 separate .DBML's in the same namespace which reference the same table and column.

Unlike in Datasets, wherein you can have 2 separate Datasets (**Dataset1.xsd** and **Dataset2.xsd**) weach ith the *same* table and *same* columns, not so in Linq.

**DataClass1.dbml** with table **MyTable** with a column **myColumn** and **DataClass2.dbml** with table also name **MyTable** with a column **myColumn** will fail because **myColumn** is defined in both designer.cs files within the same namespace.

My workaround: I 'renamed' **DataClass2.dbml's** **MyTable** to **MyTable_2** and **myColumn** to **myColumn_2**.

I then cursed Microsoft, deleted **DataClass2.dbml** and integrated the 3rd table I needed into **DataClass1.dbml**, along with other tables (to avoid this issue). **DataClass1.dbml** now has some 40 tables in it, which now causes the **DataClass1.designer.cs** file to have over 20,000 lines of 'auto-generated' code.

Lovely, eh.